# Easy | How do I get the value of one column from another column

Tags: php, sql

[image: Picture of my SQL table.]

Hi there. I just wanted to know something for a project I am working on. I'm not a very good PHP coder and however I word the question leads to a bunch of jibberish I don't understand.

If User 1's ID is 1 and login is test, how do I find their ID from the login.

Essentially, how do I find 'id' column when the 'login' column is 'test'.

If anyone can just explain it I'd love that.

Comment: While I'm sure the answer being handed to you would be convenient, it may behoove you to actually spend a little time to understand how to use SQL.

Essentially, you want to establish a connection to your database server, then write a query that would provide you with the data that you require.

Read some PHP/SQL tutorials, and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: So write and execute a simple `SELECT` query.  What's the problem?

Comment: Assuming table name of Users, `SELECT id FROM Users WHERE BINARY  login = 'test'`. The use of `BINARY` makes the comparison **case sensative**. That will get you started, now go and find some introductory MYSQL tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using phpmyadmin, and perhaps mysql. Normally, your HTML will have a form that will use POST to send the login (and password) to your PHP script. The PHP script will then have a `$_POST` variable containing all the data that was POSTed to it, including their `login`. `$_POST` is an array with named elements, and what name your `login` field is in depends on what you named the input field in the html.

After that, to get their ID it's a simple matter of querying your database with a `SELECT` query such as `SELECT id, login FROM your_table` . Look up how to run mysql queries in PHP and access the query results:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php